# Connectiong to Azure table storage from Azure databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-table-storage, azure-databricks

I am trying to connecto to azure table storage from Databricks. I can't seem to find any resources that doesn't go to blob containers, but I have tried modifying it for tables.

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.accountname.table.core.windows.net",
  "accountkey")

blobDirectPath = "wasbs://accountname.table.core.windows.net/TableName"

df = spark.read.parquet(blobDirectPath)
```

I am making an assumption for now that tables are parquet files. I am getting authentication errors on this code now.

Comment: According to my research, Azure Databricks does not support the data source of Azure table storage. For more details, please refer to https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/index.html. If you want to use table storage, you can try to use Azure Cosmos DB table api.

Comment: Looks like you are right, where planning to use Table storage to remove the SQL server, but looks like we will have to keep for a little bit more.

Comment: According to the situation, if you want to use Table storage, you can use Azure Cosmos DB Table API. But it has some differences, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#where-is-table-api-not-identical-with-azure-table-storage-behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my research, Azure Databricks does not support the data source of Azure table storage. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/external-data/.
[image: Data Sources list]

Besides if you still want to use table storage, you can use Azure Cosmos DB Table API. But they have some differences. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#where-is-table-api-not-identical-with-azure-table-storage-behavior.